# Nesting of operators in Lua does not give correct answer

Tags: lua, operators, lua-table, evaluation, metatable

The following code defines sort of custom operator *imp*. It works almost correctly.

```
    local function _imp(x, y)
      if x == 1 and y == 0 then return 0
        else return 1 end
    end
    
    local tmp = {}
    local imp = {}
    
    local imp_mult= {
      __mul = function(a,b)
        if b==imp then
          tmp[1]=a
          return tmp
        elseif a == tmp then
          return _imp(tmp[1], b)
        end
      end
    }
    
    setmetatable(tmp, imp_mult)
    setmetatable(imp, imp_mult)
    _G.imp = imp

print("0 imp 0 evaluates to ", 0*imp*0)
print("1 imp 0 evaluates to", 1*imp*0)
print("0 imp (1 imp 0) evaluates to", 0*imp*((1*imp*0)))
```

The above code outputs to

```
0 imp 0 evaluates to 1
1 imp 0 evaluates to 0
0 imp (1 imp 0) evaluates to 0
```

The first two answers are correct. However the expected answer for last expression is 1 as `0*imp*0` evaluates to 1 and `1*imp*0` evaluates to 0. Where is the mistake? How the definition of imp_mult can be improved to get expected answer?

Comment: Could you edit the question with more details about what the custom operator is supposed to do?

Comment: Lua does not support custom operator. Here *imp* is sort of custom operator (way around with metatables in Lua).

Comment: I know, if I didn't know such a simple fact I wouldn't be able to understand anything in this code. I just wanted what the metatable part is supposed to do (that's what I meant) because it would help me (and others?) understand the more complicated part.

Comment: `tmp[1]` is overwritten, that's what I can see. This causes problems. Try using an upvalue that behaves like a counter and is decremented when an operation is done. You would use the "`counter`th" index to store the value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you help by giving answer? It would really be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `tmp[1]` will be overwritten. Instead of `1`, you should use a counter variable that is incremented before the operation is done (`x * imp`), and decremented when an operation is done (`x * imp * y`).

```
local function _imp(x, y)
    if x == 1 and y == 0 then return 0
    else return 1 end
end

local tmp = {}
local imp = {}

local depth = 0

local imp_mult = {
    __mul = function(a,b)
        if b==imp then
            depth = depth + 1
            tmp[depth] = a
            return tmp
        elseif a == tmp then
            local v = _imp(tmp[depth], b)
            depth = depth - 1
            return v
        end
    end
}
    
setmetatable(tmp, imp_mult)
setmetatable(imp, imp_mult)
_G.imp = imp

print("0 imp 0 evaluates to ", 0*imp*0)
print("1 imp 0 evaluates to", 1*imp*0)
print("0 imp (1 imp 0) evaluates to", 0*imp*((1*imp*0)))
```

You can change the place of the assignment to use the `0`th index if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. The key point was unnoticed. Thanks again.

Comment: "The key point was unnoticed"? Does that mean that this answer didn't solve it? If so, what is the "key point"?

Comment: I mean I did not notice (not you) the fact that tmp[1] gets overridden. Your answer is perfect and answers my question. Thanks once again.

Comment: `local v = _imp(tmp[op], b)` does this need correction? I think  `local v = _imp(tmp[depth], b)`

Comment: @mathsbeauty It does, I missed that part when I edited the answer.